# Google Cloud Endpoint not recognizing my API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I have 699 APIs for my Cloud Endpoint will that have any effect? I am clarifying because what I have noticed is many APIs are not recognized and returns **"Method not exist"**.

Comment: How have you deployed these APIs? Are these 699 APIs in separate openapi specs, or in one openapi spec? How do you run the API code behind the Cloud Endpoint? Can you verify that the "method not exist" is originating from Endpoint, not from API backend?

Comment: Yes. I deployed thise APIs. They are only in one openapi spec. The Cloud Endooint is run via Kubernetes acting as a proxy. The method does not exist is originating from endpoint

Comment: I deployed via 'gcloud endpoint services depooy swagger.yaml'

Answer (score 1):

Could you use CLI "gcloud endpoints configs describe" to check if these "Method not exist" methods are in the service config?

Comment: path match is case sensitive.  please double check the case.

Comment: It's really the exact. Basically, I am copy pasting on the existing endpoints shown in my Cloud Endpoint GCP Console to my browser

Answer (score 1):

You can enable debug for ESP by adding flag --enable_debug to ESP container start arguments.  Then extract the log inside the ESP container at /var/log/nginx/error.log

If you can provide the service config from "gcloud endpoints configs describe <config_id> --service <service_name>" and the request URL you are sending,  it will help too.